# Google Drive low bandwidth or basic HTML view or mobile view in desktop

Tags: google-drive

I am using my smartphone as a wi-fi hotspot and have GPRS/2G/3G (selected according to location) to which my computer system connects for Internet access. Usually the speed is low, like 12 Kbytes/sec.

I want to read documents, specifically PDFs in Google Drive. It takes some time to load or doesn't load.

Is there a low bandwidth/mobile/basic-HTML view of Google Drive? This would be similar to forcing the desktop version of Google Drive to load a mobile HTML version.

I use Gmail in basic HTML view and Google AdSense in low-bandwidth version. If there could be the same for Google Drive then that would be nice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When I visit [drive.google.com](http://drive.google.com) in my Android's browser, I'm redirected to [drive.google.com/m](https://drive.google.com/m).

I can follow that URL in my desktop browser and do indeed get the mobile-optimized version of the Google Drive site.

However, as soon as I click on a PDF file, I get the usual desktop PDF viewer. I don't see a way to force the PDF viewer to be a mobile-optimized version.