# Basic HTML Version of Google Drive

Tags: google-drive

**Related question**: [Google Drive low bandwidth or basic HTML view or mobile view in desktop](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/49437/google-drive-low-bandwidth-or-basic-html-view-or-mobile-view-in-desktop)

I'm looking for a **static** (in terms of interactivity of the interface), low-bandwidth version of Google Drive (similar to the non-dynamic mobile version of Gmail (https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/x/) or the Gmail basic HTML view (https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/h/).

While the answer provided for the [related question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/49437/google-drive-low-bandwidth-or-basic-html-view-or-mobile-view-in-desktop) provides a mobile-optimized dynamic version, I'm looking for something more in the line of a static HTML website (analogous to Gmail basic HTML (https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/h/) over Gmail Mobile for smartphones (https://mail.google.com/mail/mu/)).

Comment: At this time Google doesn't offer a HTML static view but you it could be built by using the Google Drive API or Google Apps Script.

Comment: Hmm... Actually me and my friends tried it once, with one of our pet projects :) I wonder if they had a JS-driven, fully dynamic Drive site from the beginning, unlike how Gmail evolved (from the basic HTML site (https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/h/) to the sophisticated dynamic site they have now)?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Drive

Comment: @Rubén I checked, but couldn't come across anything interesting... What were you referring to?

Comment: That's weird, I found a lot of interesting information like the  "original" app was Writely, Google Drive is written in Python, just to mention a couple of interesting things :)

Comment: @Rubén Hmm... Well, by 'interesting' I meant something that would help solve my problem :)

Comment: In a previous comment you said " I wonder if they had a JS-driven, fully dynamic Drive site from the beginning..." :)

Comment: Aha, missed it! :) Thanks. Well, it's highly unlikely that Google would go back to a simple, plain HTML site for their Drive, so I guess I'm stuck here.

Comment: See [How do I ask a question that may require recommending a web app?](http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/q/3705/88163) and [What is the XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/289691)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this web address is what you have been looking for:  https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/mobile/my-drive

**Edit:** But there is no option for uploading anything. Just for see what's in the Google Drive.

Comment: Thanks. I had tried this already, but it's only slightly less bandwidth-efficient in comparison to the desktop site; more like Gmail Mobile for smartphones (https://mail.google.com/mail/mu/) against the desktop site.

Comment: **Any update?** This simply redirects to Gdrive main page